# What is the best way to find the nearest lesser and greater values in a list to a given number

Tags: c#, sequence

I have a random list of numbers say 1,8,13,20,25,32,50,55,64,70 now given a number say 35 the lesser value required will be 32 and greater value will be 50.

the way I tried to do this is by iterating all the values

---

```
        var value = 35;
        var list = new List<int> { 1, 8, 13, 20, 25, 32, 50, 55, 64, 70 };

        var lesser = list.First();
        var greater = list.Last();
        foreach (var curr in list)
        {
            if (curr >= value)
            {
                greater = curr;
                break;
            }
            lesser = curr;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Lesser Value :{0}\tGreater Value:{1}", lesser, greater);
```

---

Now the reason why I am asking this is I need to optimize for a situation where the list is generated once and then values are requested multiple times. Iterating the list for each request seems like a bad idea.

---

**Update**

The question did not specify what is required if we get an exact match, I needed the upper and lower bounds to be the matched element in that case ie, 32 should return 32 as the lesser value and 32 as the greater value in the above list.

The modified answer to reflect the same is :

```
int value = 32;
int[] list = new[] { 1, 8, 13, 20, 25, 32, 50, 55, 64, 70 };
int? floor = null;
int? ceil = null;
int index = Array.BinarySearch(list, value);
if (index >= 0) // element is found
{
    floor = ceil =list[index] ;
}
else
{
    index = ~index;
    if (index == list.Length)
    {
        ceil = floor = list[index-1];   
    }
    else
    {
        ceil = list[index];
        floor = list[((index==0)?index: index-1)];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("floor = {0}", floor);
Console.WriteLine("ceil = {0}", ceil);
```

Comment: Are you more interested in fast sorting, or in readable code?  If readable, @Ehsan's answer is the way to go.  If fast, perhaps Ulugbek's

Comment: @paqogomez Ehsan's code actually causes the iteration to happen twice rather than once as in my code. Ulugbek's answer is the best option so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int value = 35;
int[] list = new[] { 1, 8, 13, 20, 25, 32, 50, 55, 64, 70 };
int? floor = null;
int? ceil = null;
int index = Array.BinarySearch(list, value);
if (index >= 0) // element is found
{
    if (index > 0)
        floor = list[index - 1];
    if (index < list.Length - 1)
        ceil = list[index + 1];
}
else
{
    index = ~index;
    if (index < list.Length)
        ceil = list[index];
    if (index > 0)
        floor = list[index - 1];
}
Console.WriteLine("floor = {0}", floor);
Console.WriteLine("ceil = {0}", ceil);
```

Comment: good answer, actually better answer than mine performance wise..+1

Answer (score 0):

If list is sorted, you can do like this:

```
int value = 35;
var lessThan = list.TakeWhile(p => p < value).LastOrDefault();
var greaterThan = list.SkipWhile(p => p <= value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +0: Your code is essentially identical to what OP have (maybe simpler to read). Position in sorted list should be found in O(log n), not O(n)

Comment: Which part? Why your linear search is O(n) or what is complexity of binary search ?

Comment: That's not at all better than current linear search.

Comment: i have not studied complexity, i studied last time in my university course, i have to look at it now i think

Comment: This will throw an exception if there is no value less/greater than `value`

Comment: Your solution is the most readable, but it **does** iterate the list for each `value`, and the OP specifically asked how to prevent this.